# How to close a C++ VCL form and open another one on a button click?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, rad-studio

I'm having trouble closing `Form1` and opening `Form3` through a button click.

I have tried this code:

```cpp
#include "Welcome.h"
#include "Login.h"

void __fastcall TForm1::LoginButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    TForm1 *CurrentForm = new TForm1(this);
    CurrentForm->Close();
    TForm3 *NewForm = new TForm3(this);
    NewForm->Show();
}
```

This is the part of the code that is not working:

```cpp
TForm1 *CurrentForm = new TForm1(this);
CurrentForm->Close();
```

What can I change to make `Form1` close upon the button click?

Comment: `TForm1 *CurrentForm = new TForm1(this);` defines a pointer to and allocates a brand new `TForm` which is then closed (and probably leaked, but my VLC is really weak). Nothing happens to the original form that presumably contains the button that triggered this event. Sadly my VCL is too weak to even tell you how to get a pointer to the form you want to close, but it may be accessible as a parent of `sender`. There will almost certainly be a better way to do this and hopefully Remy will be along in a few minutes to show both of us.

Comment: @user4581301 the new Form object is not leaked exactly, as it has a non-null `Owner` assigned to it, so it will be freed when the `Owner` is freed.  But it will just be hanging around unused in memory in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of `CurrentForm`.  You are creating a whole new Form object just to close it immediately. You need to instead call `Close()` on the Form object that the button belongs to. And since the `OnClick` handler is a method of that Form, you can simply use the method's `this` pointer to access the Form object, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::LoginButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    Close(); // aka this->Close()
    TForm3 *NewForm = new TForm3(this);
    NewForm->Show();
}
```

Just be aware that `TForm1` is usually the default name of the `MainForm`, and if you `Close()` the `MainForm` then your app will exit.  If you need to "close" the `MainForm` without exiting the app, you can `Hide()` the `MainForm` instead.

Comment: `TForm1::`... Oh <expletive deleted> I am stupid. Of course you just use `this`.

Comment: Could be a good idea to have the manually allocated memory for `TForm3` released when `NewForm` is closed

Comment: @MatG we can't see the `TForm3` class, so we can't know if that is already being done or not (ie, via its own `OnClose` event handler). But either way, that is not relevant to the question at hand.